# logic words alternative

Tags: design, helpfile

I am using logic words to design circuits like `ALU`, on windows in class and my pc itś running only ubuntu, my question is how I can open this extension (`.cct`) on linux, please not tell me about virtual machine.

thanks.

Comment: What program are you using to create these files?

Comment: @muru i'm using logic works

Comment: @muru i'm using logic works

Comment: You might try Wine: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=7639&iTestingId=77870 or this suggestion: http://trisquel.info/en/forum/free-software-create-logicworks-files